# Do EE template partials have a preparse function similar to LowVars?

Tags: low-variables, global-variables, template-partials

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically set variables within a template partial from the point at which it is included. This works in Low Variables as the preparse function, but is there anything for partials that could include this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Template Partials are renamed Snippets. They don't support a preparse-like function, although you could try a workaround with Preload Replace vars, [as explained in this blog post from 2011](http://gotolow.com/blog/snippets-and-preload-replace-variables).